Are non‐moving animals (like oysters) included in Bereshit 9:3?
I want to determine the extent to which Bereshit 9:3 permits Noahides to eat living things in using the phrase “every moving thing that lives.” I’m particularly wondering about the “moving” part. Would a living animal that does not move, such as an (e.g., cooked) oyster, fall outside the scope of Bereshit 9:3? Or is “every moving thing that lives” equivalent to what we include today in the term “animals”?
NOTE
A number of similar questions exist:

Remes - רֶמֶשׂ - in Genesis 9:3
Genesis Chapter 9 : 3 Meaning
Can a Ben-Noach eat live oysters?

However, my question is not a duplicate of these questions for the following reasons:

The first question asks about different meanings of “moving thing,”
not whether non‐moving animals are included.
The second question asks
to explain an apparent contradiction in the verse, which is not what I’m
discussing.
The third question asks whether a Ben Noach can eat live
oysters, without addressing whether oysters in general, as non‐moving
animals, are permissible in the first place.


Oysters move around during their first three stages of life so they are exactly non-moving. Also I don't think this is literal but merely a statement about life and that living things generally move which they are allowed to consume any of these living creatures.

@Dude That only raises the question of whether movement is the defining property of an animal (as opposed to a plant), or whether the defining property is something else. See also Ikkarim 3:1: ונמצא האספוג הימיי שאין לו אלא חוש ההרגש בלבד, והוא כמו האמצעי בין הצומח והחי - the sponge is midway between plant and animal (apparently because it has feeling but lacks movement)

Rule 5 of Rabbi Yishmael's brysa, which enumerates 13 rules for how to learn the Torah, helps explain this verse. The rule is that when there is a specific followed by a general the general comes to include the specific example and more. Here the Torah is not limiting Noah and his descendants to only eat animals that have the ability to move. This is just specific thing which is followed by all living things being permitted. Furthermore, as Rashi explains... "Will be yours to eat - for I did not permit Adam, the first man, to eat meat, but only plant vegetation. To you, however, in the same way that I gave full use of plant vegetation to Adam the first man, so have I given you everything." (Translation from chabad.org)

But if oysters aren't halachically animals maybe even Adam could have eaten them.

If Adam was theoretically allowed to eat them then there's no question Noah could. That isn't the question though and I don't know if anything that would demonstrate an oyster as a plant.
